# SQL Server : create temp table in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am creating procedure for creating temporary table's but I want to make this more general instead of for just one original table's temporary

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CREATE_TEMP_TABLES]
AS 
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.TABLES 
                   WHERE NAME=N'TEMP_FactAdditional' AND type ='U')
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE dbo.TEMP_FactAdditional
        (
             [ProductKey] [int] NOT NULL,
             [CultureName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
             [ProductDescription] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
        )
    END 
GO
```

so `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.TABLES WHERE NAME=N'TEMP_FactAdditional' AND type ='U')` in here I see its only creating TEMP_FactAdditional table and I have like 8 or 9 original tables which each of them is different, `CREATE TABLE dbo.TEMP_FactAdditional` I am thinking to add some function or method to make more general but I don't have that much knowledge about it, I am designing warehouse, and my first step is to make more efficient to transfer data's from DB to DB. such as here in the photo [image: warehouse]. Can someone help me to make procedure more efficient?

Comment: FYI, A table called `TEMP_FactAdditional` is *not* a temporary table. Temporary objects start with a `#` and are not schema qualified.

Comment: Thank you for information, so #TEMP_FactAdditional is a real temporary table, does this changes, anything in SSMS?

Comment: In SSMS? What does the above have to do with SSMS?

Comment: what do you mean? I am constantly working with SSMS to design database, procedure's, temporary tables and original tables.

Comment: Bad idea, it's much easier just to create each table separately. Have you considered just getting proper ETL software to move the data?

Comment: Well I am new at Data Warehousing, I am writing thesis about data integration so I choosed the manual way lets say to learn. I cant use ETL software.

Comment: I think this is an awful idea. You are going to run into issues with session based objects with the same name, spend hours trouble shooting and eventually end up scrapping this project. save yourself the headache and abandon it now.

Comment: I can't abandon it, btw Instead of making solution everyone says its an bad idea, well I just solve my question on my own. thanks for help guys. Its my idea and I want to learn not just make it easy for me!

Comment: *"what do you mean? I am constantly working with SSMS to design database, procedure's, temporary tables and original tables."* you asked if using a temporary table changes anything in SSMS and I asked what does SSMS have to do with using Temporary tables. SSMS is just an IDE; I don't understand how or why you think temporary tables would have an affect on SSMS.

Comment: Oh sorry, I got that wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not going to comment on the overall approach, but if you want a general way to create tables to move data into, you could do something like this....

```
SELECT *
INTO my_new_table_name
FROM my_old_table_name
WHERE 1 = 0
```

This will create the new table with the same structure and no data.  Then you could theoretically write the procedure to use dynamic SQL to run this code for a list of tables, thus "creating" a number of tables in an abstract case.  You could pass in two parameters, the two table names.